# dispatch statement problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Now i move with come collection view projects.in that they get some data and display that in collection view. and in viewdidload method they did some thing cant get what is that.Here that code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //section name
   // display the title in collection view
    titleArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Tasks

       //  get data is a method which have all declaration and process for get the data and display in collection view from url using HTTP GET METHOD
        [self getdata];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Run UI Updates
            [self.mycollectionView reloadData];
        });
    });



    self.mycollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.mycollectionView.delegate = self;
```

}

1. [self getdata] is they used getdata method for all http get method. to get data from one url and display that in collection view.

2 . my doubt is;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Tasks
        [self getdata];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Run UI Updates
            [self.mycollectionView reloadData];
        });
    });
```

Why they use that `getdata, relode` method inside that `dispath`. please explain me why they use there inside that `dispath`.Please dont down vote. I have started learning. help is needed?

thanks!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Please try to clarify this question.

Comment: see my point 2. they declare that [self getdata] method inside that duspatch_async statement.thats why asking why they used that way

Comment: The main point of doing this is to not block main thread, which is the UI thread. Blocking the main thread will result in UI freeze, i.e. not responding. First dispatch is to run the getData method in background thread and second dispatch is to update UI in main thread after data is ready. You need second dispatch because UI cannot be updated in a background thread.

Comment: if i did not add that dispath statement and simply use [self getdata], relode collection view means does it will work .i.e i am asking it is needed to use in this way

Comment: @stepanferous For this example, if you completely remove the dispatch code, I think it will still work. And if there is not much data processing logic in the getData method, performance will be not affected also. But if you only remove the second dispatch code, it may not work, i.e. your data will not be shown. [if you have other question, please "@" me, so that I can see the notification.]